# Microsoft Access VBA INSERT SQL statement

Tags: ms-access

I have created a database within Microsoft access and with it a form.
I have a button attached to the form and when it's clicked I want to insert a new record into the table `customerHeader`.
There are four fields within that table one being an autonumber.  In my SQL statement, I don't include the orderNumber since it is an autofield.
When I try to click the button and the on click event is executed, I get an error saying that Microsoft Access cannot append the records in the append query.

Any ideas, I have looked everywhere and I have not been able to find the solution.

```
Private Sub addOrder_Click()
    Dim mySql As String
    Dim rowNum As Integer
    Dim recCount As Long
    Dim orderNumber As Long
    Dim myBool As Boolean


    Dim todayDate As Date

    todayDate = CDate(Date)

    myBool = False


    MsgBox todayDate

    rowNum = Form.CurrentRecord
    rowNum = CInt(rowNum - 1)



    'DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    mySql = "INSERT INTO orderHeader (orderDate,custNumber,printed) VALUES (" & todayDate & "," & rowNum & "," & myBool & ")"

    DoCmd.RunSQL mySql

    Me!orderNum.Requery
```

Comment: On its own the SQL does work, although you may want to add `#` around the date - `(#" & todayDate & "#,"` (you may also need to muck around with the date formatting depending on  your locality - I hate dates in Access).  What's the exact message it gives? Usually it says - `MS Access set x field(s) to Null due to a type conversion failure, and it didn't add x record(s).....`

Comment: It specifically says "Microsoft access set 0 field(s) to Null due to a type conversion failure, and it didn't add 1 record(s) to the table due to key violations, 0 record(s) due to lock violations, and 0 record(s) due to validation rule violations". I will try to add # to the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to much around - just use the ISO sequence for the format of the string expression for the date value:

```
mySql = "INSERT INTO orderHeader (orderDate,custNumber,printed) VALUES (#" & Format(todayDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#," & rowNum & "," & myBool & ")"
```

However, it it's today, simply use:

```
mySql = "INSERT INTO orderHeader (orderDate,custNumber,printed) VALUES (Date()," & rowNum & "," & myBool & ")"
```

Comment: I just tried that now and unfortunately, I am being given the same error as before.

Comment: Then something else is going on. Try to insert the values manually and find the offending value.

Comment: "Key violation" means that you try to insert a duplicate value in a field with a unique index.

Comment: For some reason my "myBool" variable was being handled incorrectly, so i instead got rid of the variable and used "false" and it began to work. Thank you for your suggestions and help through this problem!

Comment: Great! Have a nice weekend.